# How to redirect to HTTPS from HTTP without a redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect from `http://` to `https://` in htaccess?

I have tried;

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but it sends it to a reload loop. Is there a way of doing this without it getting into a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
# Forces SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

`X-Forwarded-Proto` is for if you are behind a hash-terminating load balancer

Comment: No redirect is made with this :(

Comment: i took that straight from a working application i built. maybe `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled? also, are you in a LAMP environment?

Comment: I went to my hosting to see what the problem was and they got my code working for me. They did something their end. Thanks